# How to read a text-file resource into Java unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a unit test that needs to work with XML file located in `src/test/resources/abc.xml`. What is the easiest way just to get the content of the file into `String`?

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656797/how-to-read-a-file-into-string-in-java

Comment: @Nikita, was going to vote to close despite my answer, but those questions don't mention `getResourceAsStream()` which I believe is the right approach for the OP's question.

Comment: @kirk, getResourceAsStream caches the file in the classloader.  That is unnecessary.

Comment: @Thorbjørn, where is your reference for that?  In any case, it certainly is *convenient and portable* which may in fact be necessary.

Comment: For Android Studio see following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/33057561/3256989

Comment: yegor256's answer not work. For my situation is 
 `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/example/ninja.txt"));`, my resource file located at com/example/ninja.txt

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. The "duplicates" provided don't answer how to read a resource file, but files in general. The problem is how to reference that resource file

Comment: I had to use a leading slash: `Bla.class.getResourceAsStream("/abc.xml")`

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Finally I found a neat solution, thanks to [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
package com.example;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
public class FooTest {
  @Test 
  public void shouldWork() throws Exception {
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(
      this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.xml"),
      "UTF-8"
    );
  }
}
```

Works perfectly. File `src/test/resources/com/example/abc.xml` is loaded (I'm using Maven).

If you replace `"abc.xml"` with, say, `"/foo/test.xml"`, this resource will be loaded: `src/test/resources/foo/test.xml`

You can also use [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org):

```
package com.example;
import org.cactoos.io.ResourceOf;
import org.cactoos.io.TextOf;
public class FooTest {
  @Test 
  public void shouldWork() throws Exception {
    String xml = new TextOf(
      new ResourceOf("/com/example/abc.xml") // absolute path always!
    ).asString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can do this as simply without external library dependency.

Comment: Should we close InputStream in this case?

Comment: @dbf good question... I think we should, but since it's a unit test, we don't really care :)

Comment: In which path have you stored "abc.xml"?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer see the update of the answer

Comment: @yegor256 since it's a unit test closing resources is *particularly* important. "Unit" tests should be fast and self contained, leaving resources open, potentially for the duration of the test run, means at best your tests run slower, and at worst fail in difficult-to-diagnose ways.

Comment: Just as compact, but with proper closing of the input stream: `IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResource("foo.xml"),
                               "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Hey @yegor256, isn't `IOUtils.toString` static method? How would you solve it now, according to your well known `static` dislike?

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz I can't solve it anyhow else, because all I have from Apache is this static method. Would be great, if they would provide, say, `FileAsString` class, which constructor would be used instead of this static method

Comment: Just in case if getClass().getResourceAsStream() gives a nullpointer. Try to get it from Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream....

Comment: This only works if the file is located in the same package. What if they are not in the same package

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz to solve that problem I created [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org), see the updated answer :)

Comment: I had to use an absolute path, otherwise `getResource()` would return `null`. So this works correctly for me: `this.getClass().getResource("/my-test-file.txt")`

Comment: This worked for me `IOUtils.toString(
      this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.xml"),
      "UTF-8"
    );`

Comment: This explain well and resolve all confusion 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres

Comment: Since java 9 without library :) -> `new String(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName).readAllBytes());`

Comment: For Java11 you can use this without an additional dependency:                
`Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("abc.xml").getPath());
                         
String string = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Solution does not work from static context.

Comment: Since Apache Commons 2.6 you can use `resourceToString` instead for cleaner code: `String xml = IOUtils.resourceToString("/com/example/abc.xml", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`. Please note the file path must be absolute in this case.

Answer (score 171):

Right to the point :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/test.xml").getFile());
```

Comment: Works for me when using junit test and want to setup test by loading xls file into byte[] form.

Comment: OP asks "What is the easiest way just to get the content of the file into String?" This answer would be even better if it directly answered that.

Comment: getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.xml");

Comment: File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/responses/example.json").getFile()); 

Seems to work just fine too, without getClassLoader().

Comment: This won't work if your method is static.

Comment: As it's mentioned in the question, I need a `String`, not a `File`

Answer (score 100):

Assume UTF8 encoding in file - if not, just leave out the "UTF8" argument & will use the 
default charset for the underlying operating system in each case.

**Quick way in JSE 6 - Simple & no 3rd party library!**

```
import java.io.File;
public class FooTest {
  @Test public void readXMLToString() throws Exception {
        java.net.URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("test/resources/abc.xml");
        //Z means: "The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any"
        String xml = new java.util.Scanner(new File(url.toURI()),"UTF8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
  }
}
```

**Quick way in JSE 7**

```
public class FooTest {
  @Test public void readXMLToString() throws Exception {
        java.net.URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("test/resources/abc.xml");
        java.nio.file.Path resPath = java.nio.file.Paths.get(url.toURI());
        String xml = new String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(resPath), "UTF8"); 
  }
```

**Quick way since Java 9**

```java
new String(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName).readAllBytes());
```

Neither intended for enormous files though.

Comment: the 2nd example doesn't work, readAllBytes doesn't seem to accept URL... the closest I got to make it work is `String xml = new String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(url.toURI())), "UTF8");`

Comment: It does work - needs an argument of type Path.  That's why I called it resPath.  :)

Comment: Am I missing something?  You create the variable `url` and don't use it, and use a variable `resPath` without having creating it.  Seems important to include the magic that makes it work.

Comment: Oop.  Fixed - added missing line.  Now I understand prior confusion in comments :-$

Comment: @GlenBest - Could you clarify what an "enormous file" is?

Comment: The above reads the file contents directly into a string in memory.  So, for example, if you have 4GB of memory, then a file of somewhere between 1-4GB probably classifies as "enormous" because it will consume a very significant proportation of memory resources (page swapping to disk, aside).  For large files, better to stream - read in chunks, not all at once.

Comment: java7 version is perfect, tip: use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 to avoid the unsupportedEncodingException

Comment: Can you explain why you're using MyClass rather than for example FoTest and when you want to use which class?

Comment: Well done on adding the full package names in your example.  That is ALWAYS helpful.

Comment: I got it working with the slash at the start of the file name `MyClass.class.getResource("/test/resources/abc.xml")`

Comment: the r java 9 solution giving the result as a string directly!

Answer (score 16):

First make sure that `abc.xml` is being copied to your output directory.  Then you should use `getResourceAsStream()`:

```
InputStream inputStream = 
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test/resources/abc.xml");
```

Once you have the InputStream, you just need to convert it into a string.  This resource spells it out: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/266.html.  However, I'll excerpt the relevent code:

```
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    } else {        
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `your output directory`?

Comment: @Vincenzo, usually "classes" though perhaps "bin".  i.e. wherever you are compiling your classes to.  Most IDEs already copy resource files such as xml files to that directory so you should probably take a quick peak and see if it's already there.

Comment: Looks like too much code in your case. I would better use some `apache.commons.io.*` class for file reading, and `java.lang.Class.getResource()`. What do you think?

Comment: A nice way to test it would be if you write the test cases in a ".properties" file with testKey = value and then you can load the InputStream directly. Example: Properties properties = new Properties(); properties.load(inputStream); String testCase = properties.getProperty("testKey");

Comment: How to make that `abc.xml` be copied to output directory? @KirkWoll

Answer (score 14):

With the use of Google Guava:

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Resources;

public String readResource(final String fileName, Charset charset) throws Exception {
        try {
            return Resources.toString(Resources.getResource(fileName), charset);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
}
```

Example:

```
String fixture = this.readResource("filename.txt", Charsets.UTF_8)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try doing:

```
String myResource = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.xml")).replace("\n","");
```

Comment: Why are you stripping new lines?

Comment: @zudduz i'm sorry i don't remember, this was 2 years ago

Comment: IOUtils.toString toString(stream) is also deprecated. A Charsets needed to be passed in IOUtils.toString toString(stream, Charsets.UTF_8) (import com.google.common.base.Charsets;)

Comment: Actually to avoid deprecation, it should be : String myResource = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.xml"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replace("\n","");

Answer (score 3):

OK, for JAVA 8, after a lot of debugging
I found that there's a difference between

```
URL tenantPathURI = getClass().getResource("/test_directory/test_file.zip");
```

and

```
URL tenantPathURI = getClass().getResource("test_directory/test_file.zip");
```

Yes, the `/` at the beginning of the path without it I was getting `null`!

and the `test_directory` is under the `test` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what i used to get the text files with text. I used commons' IOUtils and guava's Resources.

```
public static String getString(String path) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = Resources.getResource(path).openStream()) {
        return IOUtils.toString(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest, using [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
IOUtils.resourceToString("/foo/text.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Junit Rule to create this temporary folder for your test:

```java
@Rule public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
File file = temporaryFolder.newFile(".src/test/resources/abc.xml");
```

Comment: @JohannesRabauer It accesses the file that OP asked for, on every test run.

Comment: in every run of the test, a new temporary folder is created. In this folder a new file "...abc.xml" is created. This means with your code the already existing file in "src/test/resources/abc.xml" is not accessed but a different file is created.

Answer (score 1):

Using Commons.IO, this method works from EITHER a instance method or a static method:

```
public static String loadTestFile(String fileName) {
    File file = FileUtils.getFile("src", "test", "resources", fileName);
    try {
        return FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error loading test file: " + fileName, e);
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [okio](https://square.github.io/okio/file_system/) in your project:

```kotlin
val text = FileSystem.RESOURCES.source("abc.xml".toPath()
  .buffer()
  .readString()
```