# How to refer to reasources/files in the same jar?

Tags: java, file-io, jar, relative-path, filepath

I have a jar file that contains two files in the root
tbs.jar
-parser.dat
-MapScript.txt
I've tried to access them with:
getClass().getResource("parser.dat")
and I also tried:
getClass().getResource("/parser.dat")
but neither works.  The class that I'm using, the class I call "getClass" on, belongs to a package that lies in the same jar.  So how am I supposed to refer to the files in the same jar, should I perhaps try "../parser.dat"?  Nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: getClass().getResource("/parser.dat") should work. Show us the code you're using to access the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
getClass().getResource("parser.dat")
```

with

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("parser.dat")
```

Comment: @eon If I am trying same thing using command line what things I need to do
-jar myjar.jar config/spring-context.xml myJob argu1 argu2
spring-context.xml file contains inside config folder inside jar.

Comment: @Kamini see Jon Skeet's post here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068197/utils-read-resource-text-file-to-string-java