# Fastest way for read an entire text file in one line Java

Tags: java, input

I've got a class in which constructor should collaborate.

```
public class Text(){
    private String text;

    public Text(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Text(InputStream input){
        this(AND NOW?);
    }
}
```

I tried using Scanner... but 1.I cant close it 2.It is too slow.

How i can read all text in one line in the fastest way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Utils read resource text file to String (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068197/utils-read-resource-text-file-to-string-java)

Comment: Personally, I'd probably make the "one line" a call to a function I'd written to read the file.

Comment: @keshiam I created a method how you have wroten :D