# How do I map a path to a static HTML file?

Tags: java, html, static, spark-java

This is the simplest example where we map a path to a `String`, so we are responsible to build the whole HTML:

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
```

We can also use template engines that will build the HTML for us given the `ModelAndView`:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", "Sam");

// hello.html file is in resources/templates directory
get("/hello", (rq, rs) -> new ModelAndView(map, "hello"), new ThymeleafTemplateEngine());
```

Now, what if I want to map a path to a static HTML file, where I don't have any variables to be interpreted by a template engine? I know I could simply use an empty map:

```
get("/static", (rq, rs) -> new ModelAndView(new HashMap(), "static"), new ThymeleafTemplateEngine());
```

But then I would be going through the engine's overhead without any reason.

I know I could also read the HTML file and return it as a `String`, like this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hallison/1010935) did. But I feel there might be a cleaner way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a staticfiles location and reference html there directly.

```
Spark.staticFileLocation("/static");
```

Create a folder called static under your `resources` directory.

```
/src/main/resources/static
```

Put your static html in this file (e.g., test.html)

Now you can access the files directly via the browser as;

http://localhost:8080/test.html

Comment: By using `staticFileLocation()`? And how would I exactly reference the HTML? Just returning its path?

Comment: Yes. Full path to the file under the static folder name

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I will edit my question with the tests I made.

Comment: So simple! But is there a way to map paths to the static file?

Comment: Spark uses jetty underneath. You can try using ResourceHandler.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421518/4893160) describes a fun way to serve a html file :)

Comment: Hahah, it's fun indeed. Thanks! It's probably the cleanest way to transform the file into a `String` and then just serve it to the simple `get` from Spark. Way better than the gist I pointed in my question.