# Passing JSON result to JSONObject or String Constructor

Tags: java, json

Below is the result of my JSON:

```
{"imageSignature":"","serviceAmount":"0","regionCode":"SG","MCPTID":"90","brandName":"MasterCard"}
```

Now when i try to pass to JSONObject It Gives syntax Error ("Syntax Error on tokes,delete these tokens"):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{"imageSignature":"","serviceAmount":"0","regionCode":"SG","MCPTID":"90","brandName":"MasterCard"}");
```

It Works fine when i do ESCAPE manually:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"imageSignature\":\"\",\"serviceAmount\":\"0\",\"regionCode\":\"SG\",\"MCPTID\":\"90\",\"brandName\":\"MasterCard\"}");
```

SO can please someone tell me how can i pass the same to JSONObject() .??

Comment: Why do you need the JSON string in your source code? Better put it in a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068197/utils-read-resource-text-file-to-string-java

Comment: I still don't understand how a JSON **result** needs to be hard-coded (in source or resource). Isn't this String the result of a previous operation?

Comment: @user2888996 What do you mean about JSON **result**?

Comment: I am Writing Util Class which takes JSON data and the Parse it.
My data is :

{
    "imageSignature": "",
    "serviceAmount": "0"
}

Answer (score 0):

> Now when i try to pass to JSONObject It Gives syntax Error ("Syntax
>   Error on tokes,delete these tokens"):

When you are manually creating `String constant` in java, you have to escape the double quotes.

> It Works fine when i do ESCAPE manually:

**Escaping the double quotes with backslashes is the only way to do this
in java.**

You can also store the string in some file and read read and pass `string object to JsonObject constructor`

> SO can please someone tell me how can i pass the same to JSONObject()

Escaping the double quotes with backslashes is the correct approach

Comment: Alternative to blackslashes: Use single quotes in the String literal and then call `replace` on it (assuming there are no single quotes in the literal itself).

Comment: @Thilo though of the same, but names of people and other text might contain single quotes, just to be on a safer side, we can go with above. :)

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have to keep JSON result to file and then read .??

Comment: Also, single quote needs to quoted itself (in the replace). One could use `*` and `replace('*', '"')`. With a literal, you know what character is "unused". But best to put in a text file, as you say.

Comment: @user2888996 then put it inside text file, read and pass `string object` to `JsonObject` constructor

Comment: @Thilo 
All Your solution (replace) will work when I am able to pass JSON result.
But as i said It given Syntax Error Even you pass into new String(""),
So basically I want to know How can i pass my JSON result directly to any of the functions?

Comment: @user2888996 better you post your complete program, somewhere you are messing up with the code.

Comment: @ankur-singhal

Expecting JSON result:

 { "imageSignature": "", "serviceAmount": "0" }

Now i want to pass to Sting :
String str =new String ("Above result");

I think it is clear now

Comment: @user2888996 above is very much parseable after escaping, you still have not posted the complete code, your utility class etc