# With Maven how do I build two versions of a Java project with just one different .java file?

Tags: java, maven

I want to build two versions of an application, the only difference is I want to swap in a different version of one particular `.java` file. I already have a Maven build for building the source, plus an Ant build to then package up as a `zip` with an embedded JRE.

So I can modify my Ant build to create another `zip` file for this new build but what would be the best way to handle the rebuilding of the source with the single amended source file?

Updated With Progress

I have now subclassed the starting class with the `main()` method, so no longer have to swap source files around instead we simply need to pass a difference value for the `mainClass` in the manifest and we now only have one source tree to build.

So in my `pom.xml` I have :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                                  <mainClass>com.companyname.StartClass</mainClass>
                    <packageName>com.companyname</packageName>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

So can I have multiple of these assembly plugins so I can build two assemblies just differing in the manifest?

Comment: How do you change this source file between builds? Is it possible to achieve different runtime behaviour by accessing a resource config file? BTW, You don't have to use a separate Ant build. The [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) can be configured in your project's POM to do exactly this.

Comment: @GeroldBrosser 'How do you change this source file between builds? ' that is the crux of the matter, and for me a better solution than using a config file to achieve the  difference.

Comment: Actually I meant how you change the content of the source file alternately. Do you overwrite it from two different locations every time? Do you change it manually?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I havent done it yet thats why Im asking the question.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I cant get profiles to work , posted a nother simpler question if you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299040/how-do-i-make-this-maven-pom-have-two-profiles-only-difference-being-in-mainclas please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is against a few of Maven's core concepts:

- One project has one [`<build>/<sourceDirectory>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM) that leads to one artifact.
- An artifact with the same name (`<finalName>` derived from `<artifactId>` and `<version>` by default) is supposed to have the same content.

There are a few solutions:

- A [property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) from a property file that's evaluated in an `if` to achieve different runtime behaviour. You don't prefer that.
- A [property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) defined via command line that's evaluated in an `if`.
- A [text from a resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068197/utils-read-resource-text-file-to-string-java) that's evaluated in an `if`.  You don't prefer that.
- A [command line argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) that's evaluated in an `if`.
- A [Java assertion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html), but cited from there: "*Do not use assertions to do any work that your application requires for correct operation.*".

One Maven way would be:

- Create two additional projects (B, C) in addition to your current (A). A can be the [parent of B and C to inherit common declarations](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance).
- B and C contain just the different source files.
- Introduce two [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Profiles_in_POMs) in A's POM with `<dependencies>` and select one of the various activation methods:

```
  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>B</id>
      <activation>
        ...
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.example</groupId>
          <artifactId>B</artifactId>
          <version>...</version>              
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>AwithB</finalName>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>C</id>
      <activation>
        ...
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.example</groupId>
          <artifactId>C</artifactId>
          <version>...</version>              
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>AwithC</finalName>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
```

Remember the second concept at the beginning: same name, same content (and behaviour). You can use the `<finalName>` declaration in the profiles to adapt A's name accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question not sure how its fits in with your answer.

Comment: Your answer didnt solve my problem but sounds like it is essentially correct so Ive marked it as so.