# NPE while try to get Resource in jar

Tags: java, maven

I have tried many variants but I cant find correct.

I have something like

Inside my jar, which created by Maven I can see that [image]

That is my folder with classes. And, by the way, If I start my program in IDEA, not from Console, there is not any exception with paths [image]

Here, I am in debug mode start my jar trying to see, where is the problem.
If I do 'file.exists()' it would be false but file inside. I think, that problem because of '.jar!\' in the path, but I don`t know how to remove that.

Anyway I've tried absolute and relative path, I've tried

```
Thread.getCurrentThread.getContextLoader.getResource()
GUI.class.getResource()
GUI.class.getClassLoader.getResource()
```

Nothing help [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `File` to open resources inside a jar file. File can only be used with normal files and directories.

Note: using File works fine within in the IDE, since all files are not packaged in a jar file yet. But the program will break after you package it.

Once you locate the resource eg. `URL res = GUI.class.getResource("/rxtx64/myres.dll")` , you can open that resource as a stream `InputStream is = res.openStream();` .

See also related answers [Utils to read resource text file to String (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068197/utils-to-read-resource-text-file-to-string-java) and [How to read a text-file resource into Java unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891375/how-to-read-a-text-file-resource-into-java-unit-test)

Comment: So, should I now, not just copy from 1 directory to another, Now, I have to read InputStream and then write that Stream to other folder?