# Difference between getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() and getClass.getResource()?

Tags: java

What is the difference between `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` and `getClass.getResource()`?

When retrieving files from resources, which one should I use in what circumstances?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream

Comment: Basically (from the question @Reimeus linked) the way the relative path lookups work. `Class.getResource` looks it up relative to the class's package, and `ClassLoader.getResource` doesn't.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The second one calls the first one. The difference is described in the javadoc.

The first one takes paths that don't start with a `/`, and always starts at the root of the classpath.

The second one takes path that can start with a `/`. If it does, it starts at the root of the classpath. If not, it starts at the package of the class on which the method is called.

So `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("foo/bar.txt")` is equivalent to `getClass().getResource("/foo/bar.txt")`.

And, assuming getClass() returns a class that is in the package `foo`, `getClass().getResource("bar.txt")` is equivalent to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("foo/bar.txt")`

Comment: thanks for the answer. suggestion: instead of "first one", "second one", you could have updated the answer little bit more readable.

Answer (score 36):

> which one should I use in what circumstances?

Neither. You should call `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`.

This has the benefit of not needing to be changed depending on whether you're calling from a static or instance method.

And more important, it will properly handle classloader delegation inside a container. If you don't use it, you might find that an "application" resource isn't found because the class that's loading it was loaded by a classloader higher up the delegation hierarchy.

Answer (score 12):

Basically, `Class.getResource()` allows you to specify a path relative to the package of the class, whereas `ClassLoader.getResource()` is always an "absolute" path.

So:

```
foo.bar.Baz.class.getResource("data.txt")
```

is equivalent to:

```
some.Other.class.getResource("/foo/bar/data.txt")
```

and they're both equivalent to:

```
some.Other.class.getClassLoader().getResource("foo/bar/data.txt")
```

(Assuming `some.Other` and `foo.bar.Baz` are loaded by the same classloader, of course.)