# getSource in Java gets error

Tags: java

My project JavaBasic gets `NullPointerException` at this line :

```
url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/JavaBasic/res/sfx_wing.wav");
```

I think my getResource method get problems and it's relevant to Classpath, how can I set it ? Thanks!

Comment: Provide error logs and what you already tried to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Put the file sfx_wing.wav at the at level of the package of class calling the url. This if the class calling the url is in the package stackoverflow, put the file at the same level as the stackoverflow.

```
my-java-project
  src
    stackoverflow
     ClassCallingUrl
    sfx_wing.wav
```

Then used this call.

```
url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sfx_wing.wav");
```

OR

```
url =this.getClass().getResource("/sfx_wing.wav");
```

Much explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres).

Comment: Please see the other alternative that I added.

Comment: I've just tried creating a package and move .wav file to it, then set path to start from the package's name the it works fine.

Comment: Cool, I'm very happy to have been of help.