# Input == null with using ImageIO.read

Tags: java

Here is the code that I am using:

```
/**
 * This method loads an image
 * 
 * @param path - path of the image
 * 
 * 
 */
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   input == null!
>   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>   at io.deadspace.graphics.ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:19)
>   at io.deadspace.graphics.asset.assets.EntityAssets.initEntityAssets(EntityAssets.java:15)
>   at io.deadspace.graphics.asset.Assets.init(Assets.java:37)
>   at io.deadspace.Game.init(Game.java:73)
>   at io.deadspace.Game.run(Game.java:127)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I recently re-did the way I loaded images into my game, it worked fine before, but now, it doesn't work anymore. I've tried both getResource and getResourceAsStream.

Here are some examples of how I am loading the images:

```
public void initEntityAssets() {
    sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("res/textures/sheet.png"));

    wood = sheet.crop(width, height, width, height);
    tree = sheet.crop(0, 0, width, height * 2);
    rock = sheet.crop(0, height * 2, width, height);
    rockDropItem = sheet.crop(1, height * 2, width, height);

}

public void initHotbarAssets() {
    sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("res/textures/sheet.png"));

    hotbar = sheet.crop(0, height * 4, width, height);
    hotbar_selected = sheet.crop(0, height * 5, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Also consider loading image once and reusing it.

Answer (score 0):

your path should be relative to the class path root, so it should be

```
sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("/res/textures/sheet.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If res is inside the java folder of the project structure you must use:

```
 ImageLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)
```

The reason is described here:

[Difference between getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() and getClass.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres)

Another solution instead of using getClassLoader() is adding a slash in the path so it begin searching in the root path.

```
/res/something
```

instead of res/something

Comment: this fixed it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: please upvote or accept the answer