# My file can't be loaded when i try to used as test resources

Tags: java, junit, apache-commons

Here is my project structure: I have an `xml file` that I need to use it with my `junit test case`, I don't know why I can not get this file.

Even I mark the directory as test directory resources with intellij and there is no way.
[image]

Here is my method:

```
@Before
    public void init() throws Exception {

        xml = IOUtils.toString(
                this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("reponse.xml"),
                "UTF-8"
        );
        ......
    }
```

I'm getting always the same error trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1906)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:803)
        at fr.gouv.crpcen.restitution.ParserServiceTest.init(ParserServiceTest.java:113)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change "reponse.xml" to "/reponse.xml"

Comment: When you use a relative path (not starting with a “/“) to load a resource, it loaded relative to the class from which getResourceAsStream() is invoked

Comment: so, it was a searching on the same level where my calss is created ( i.e the package java ? ) i mean when the path is without the "/"

Comment: @Feres.o : This question should shed some light about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres

Answer (score 1):

You missed some small detail, without this thing it wouldn't work.

Here is fixed version:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {

    xml = IOUtils.toString(
            this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/response.xml"),
            "UTF-8"
    );
    ......
}
```

I checked it works like charming.