# How should I use getResource()?

Tags: java, javafx, resources

I use getResource() to load the image, but I get nullpointer exception. Also I tried to use css but I get nothing.
My code for label:

```
        Image mine = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("bomb3.png"));
        ImageView im = new ImageView(mine);

        Label label = new Label();

        label.setGraphic(im);
```

And for button:

```
btn.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('flag.png')");
```

This code is located in Painter class.

My file tree:

[image: file tree]

Comment: try `getResourceAsStream("./main/resources/bomb3.png")`

Comment: @ZOLDIK I feel that it won't work !

Comment: if the resources folder is in src then `getResourceAsStream("/resources/bomb3.png")`

Comment: It _looks_ like you have `src/main/java` and `src/resources` but the latter should actually be `src/main/resources`. If that's the case then fix the directory layout and afterwards `"/bomb3.png"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("bomb3.png")` java search in the packetof your class. So if your class is Game, your resource must be in the packet: com.name.minesweeperClasses

Answer (score -3):

```
Image mine = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("bomb3.png"));
```

here path of bomb3.png is incorrect 
Please mention the relative path :-
./resources/boob3.png

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres

Comment: This path is not going to work. "./bomb3.png" is more correct I think

Comment: no - please don't post random variations of paths, instead read and understand the api doc of the method and explain (by citing/explaining that doc) why one variant will work while the other doesn't) Hint: your variant is even worse - will never work - than the original (which might work if the resource would be in the top-level package)

Comment: @D.Lawrence - no, periods are not supported in resolving a resource path