# How do I have common file path for Windows and Linux in Junit Test Suite?

Tags: java, junit

My Junit test suite configured to execute in Windows and Linux environment. I developed 2 possibilities of code to achieve the same. I am really not sure about the OS independent behaviour with below code. I am new to java. Please suggest.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String directoryRootFromFile = null;
        String directoryRootFromUserDir = null;
        String propertiesPath = null;
        directoryRootFromFile = new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()  + File.separatorChar + "data";
        directoryRootFromUserDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separatorChar + "data";
        propertiesPath = directoryRootFromFile + File.separatorChar + "abc.properties";
        System.out.println(propertiesPath);
        propertiesPath = directoryRootFromUserDir + File.separatorChar + "abc.properties";
        System.out.println(propertiesPath);
    }   

1st Output : C:\workspace\test\.\data\abc.properties
2nd Output : C:\workspace\test\data\abc.properties
```

Comment: Did you test it? Does it work on both Linux and Windows? What is the question?

Comment: You should add the files to the classpath and load ad with Class.getResource()

Comment: @Jim - I tested with Windows and attached the result. 1st output is not an valid file path.

Comment: Actually, it _is_ a valid path.  If you want to see it cleaned up, do `Paths.get(directoryRootFromFile).normalize().toString()`.

Comment: related: [How to read a text-file resource into Java unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891375/how-to-read-a-text-file-resource-into-java-unit-test/13227067#13227067)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative paths. Do not manipulate paths as `String`s; rather, use the `Path` and `Paths` classes. Use the JUnit `TemporaryFolder` class to create a test fixture that is automatically set up and torn down for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this option.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following source layout.

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── test
        │       └── FileTest.java
        └── resources
            └── data
                └── abc.properties
```

Where `abc.properties` has the following contents.

```
foo=foo property value
bar=bar property value
```

The following tests passes.

```
@Test
public void test() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String testRoot = this.getClass().getResource("/").getFile();

    Path path = Paths.get(testRoot, "data", "abc.properties");

    File file = new File(path.toUri());

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(file));

    assertEquals("foo property value", prop.get("foo"));
    assertEquals("bar property value", prop.get("bar"));

}
```