# Jigsaw read resources from tests

Tags: junit, resources, java-platform-module-system

Hi I got trouble reading resources fromn unit tests when using jigsaw in my project

If I do this:

```
  MyClass.class.getResource("...");
```

it returns null because the resource is looked for within "${project.basedir}/target/test-classes". A workaround is to get the url and execute:

```
resource.getFile().replace("test-classes", "classes");
```

but this is a pretty dirty way in reading these resources... Is there any other clean way in doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a text-file resource into Java unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891375/how-to-read-a-text-file-resource-into-java-unit-test)

Comment: no the problem you linked here is not related.