# Netbeans plugin - Get number of lines of every class in an opened project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I am coding a Netbeans plugin that will show some statistics of the project that a developer is coding.

For example: a developer is working on a Java project. When he clicks the plugin button, it opens a window that shows the statistics of the project that he is working on.

In order to do that, first, I need to know how can I get the number of lines that each class of the project that he is working on has.

Can anyone explain how can I manage to do that? I couldn't find anything that could help me on Google.

Comment: There's already some good answers for this question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661636/how-to-count-lines-in-a-netbeans-project

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what I am looking for. For what I undestand, this can be used to count the number of lines, etc... of the project that I am working on. I want to count the number of lines of a project that someone opened through my own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Full Disclosure**:  This is copied and pasted from my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661636/how-to-count-lines-in-a-netbeans-project).  The part I think you are most likely to find interesting is here:

```
                    long lineCount = 0;
                    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        lineCount++;
                    }
```

To see it in context, please see the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36085845/1504950).  It supports millions of lines of code, and no external libraries are required.