# Reading a whole file with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to sum the length of all the lines of a file using spark. 
These lines are formatted as follows :

```
A1004AX2J2HXGL\tB0007RT9LC\tMay 30, 2005\t3\n\t4\t5.0\tLes carottes sont cuites
```

To achieve my aim, I tried this code given in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#basics) :

```
JavaRDD<String> txtFile = sc.textFile(filePath);
JavaRDD<Integer> linesLength = txtFile.map(s -> s.length());    
long totalLength = linesLength.reduce((a, b) -> a+b);
```

However, it doesn't work. For instance, for a 5.8GB text file, it returns 1602633268 when it should return 5897600784. 
I suppose it is due to the fact that some lines may contain strange characters,
which stop the reading for the line.

With goold old Java, this problem could be solved with a BufferedReader, like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330695/java-scanner-not-going-through-entire-file). However, I found no mentions of something similar for Spark in the documentation.

How could I proceed ?

Comment: How do you know 1602633268 is wrong?

Comment: I checked without using Spark.

Comment: And what was the answer? Also is the file compressed?

Comment: 5897600784 (question edited). The file is not compressed, it's a simple text file.

Comment: Reading the one give line in the spark shell it seemed to have no problems, both using a string and reading the text from a file resulted in length 79

Comment: This line is no trouble. I didn't find which one is causing trouble (still working on it though)

Comment: Cut the file in half, find which half has the problem, cut in half again, until you find the line.

Comment: as long as it doesn't have a ridiculous amount of lines, just `collect()` the length of each line

Comment: In fact, in was just an integer overflow. Nothing exotic there :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add it all wrong, it was just an integer overflow. I made it work by changing Integer to Long :

```
JavaRDD<String> txtFile = sc.textFile(path);
JavaRDD<Long> linesLength = txtFile.map(s -> Long.valueOf(s.length()));
Long totalLength = linesLength.reduce((a, b) -> a +b);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you already found at least part of your problem and answered the question, but I'd like to point out another problem: you are counting *characters* in this Spark code, but sounds like you are trying to find the file size in *bytes*. These are not at all necessarily the same thing.

Comment: I know this isn't exact but if the file is uncompressed and you are counting bytes, why even run a spark job, the file is 5.8 giga "bytes"

Comment: I guess it depends on what wrote the file out - i.e. whether it was written as ASCII or UTF. If it was written as ASCII the numbers should be the same. If it was written as UTF it will be 1x,2x or 4x PLUS the length of the BOM.  Hey Sean, is it possible to configure Spark as to which UTF to use?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651969/control-configure-set-apache-spark-utf-encoding-for-writting-as-saveastextfile

Comment: It delegates to Hadoop's TextInputFormat underneath. I think it always uses UTF8 or at least that was true last time I looked a year ago. I imagine you can manage to read something else with custom coding.