# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading from a file

Tags: java, file, exception

I have the following method that reads a file where it has an **ID** (int) and **Content** (String) separated by a tab. My method reads the file line by line, and using the tab delimiter, I parse the **ID** and the string into a doubly linked list like so:

```
void readAndAssemble(String fileName)
    {
        Scanner sc;
        try
    {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String lines[] = line.split("\t");
            int packetID = Integer.parseInt(lines[0]);
            // -----------------------------------------
            String packetContent = lines[1]; // gives error in terminal
            // -----------------------------------------
            DLLNode curr = header.getNext();
            DLLNode prev = header;
            while (packetID > curr.getPacketID())
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.getNext();
            } 
            DLLNode newNode = new DLLNode(packetID, packetContent, prev, curr);
            prev.setNext(newNode);
            curr.setPrev(newNode);

        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }

}
```

This method works perfectly in **Eclipse** when I run it, but gives me this error when I use **javac** and run it in **terminal**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at DLL.readAndAssemble(DLL.java:40)
at MessageAssembler.main(MessageAssembler.java:11)
```

Where my MessageAssembler class looks like this:

```
public class MessageAssembler
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DLL myDLL = new DLL();
        myDLL.readAndAssemble("Mystery3.txt");
        myDLL.printContent();
    }
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Either of the below lines you may have issues int packetID = Integer.parseInt(lines[0]);
            // -----------------------------------------
            String packetContent = lines[1]; // gives error in terminal. Check the line number 11 in the code .

Comment: Could you post part of the file?

Comment: You can find it at 
http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2016-17/W/2011/Mystery.txt

Comment: as per my answer `error with line 11
`

Comment: this is actually line 117 of your file - something strange

Comment: I downloaded and saved this file as dos format and it now runs OK

Comment: It works okay now. I do not know why it worked fine in eclipse, but not on terminal. But it works fine after I redownloaded it. It's weird because they are the same files.

Comment: Unless I use `vi` to save as dos format it does not work for me **even** using eclipse.  something strange about the file

Comment: @JohnDoe There seems to be a problem with using Scanner on a unix file, see my latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have lines in your file that do not conform to your understanding.

try doing

```
 String lines[] = line.split("\t");
 if (lines.length < 2) {
    System.err.println ("error with line " + line);
    continue;
 }
```

There seems to be a problem with using Scanner on a `unix` file

try

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:/temp/a.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String line;

    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (line);
      String [] lines = line.split ("\t");
      if (lines.length < 2) {
            System.err.println ("error with line " + line);
            continue;
         }        

    }

    //Close the input stream
    br.close();
```

Comment: Found a duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331416/2310289 answered by @HovercraftFullOfEels