# Scanning a Long file into a java map

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to read a text file that I created using another code to fill out a map however the scanner keeps on stopping early, however if I remove the line in the text doc where it stops the scanner will continue on for a while before getting stuck again. I can't see why it would be getting stuck on certain lines though. I added a link to the text doc that I am scanning through. For instance no matter when it is written the first instance of the castlevania line will clog up the system, in the doc it shows up at line 307. If that line is removed it crahses at stops at Conta on line 383. Then if that is removed it breaks at Dig Dug on line 479. It continues in this way of stopping on random lines that seem to have no relation, in name or line number.
[TextDocDownload](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=43575280611144460107)

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Read {
public static  PrintWriter writer;
public static Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> connectionsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String,String>>() ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setUp();
    Iterator it = connectionsMap.entrySet().iterator();
    int i =0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() +" "+i);
        i++;
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
public static void setUp() {
    File file = new File("Degrees.txt");//file with all the connections
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String description = "";
        String key="";//key for map of main series
        String secondKey="";//key for map of a mian serieses connections
        String text = "";
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String see = scanner.next();
            if(see.equals("TITLEEND")) {
                key=text;
                text="";
            }
            if(see.equals("CONNECTIONTITLEEND")) {
                secondKey=text;
                text="";
            }
            if(see.equals("DESCRIPTIONEND")||see.equals("TERMINATE")) {
                description =text;
                text="";
                mapMaker(key,secondKey,description, false);

            }if(!see.equals("TERMINATE")&&!see.equals("CONNECTIONTITLEEND")&&!see.equals("DESCRIPTIONEND")&&!see.equals("TITLEEND")) {
                if(text.length()<1)text=see;
                else text+=" "+see;
            }

        }   
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void mapMaker(String key, String secondKey, String description, boolean recursed) { 
    if(!connectionsMap.containsKey(key)) {
        connectionsMap.put(key, new LinkedHashMap<String,String>());
    }if(!connectionsMap.get(key).containsKey(secondKey)) {
        connectionsMap.get(key).put(secondKey, description);
    }

if(!recursed) {
    mapMaker(secondKey,key,description,true);
}
```

}

Comment: What line(s) in the file is it getting stuck on? (You can edit your question to include them.)

Comment: the problem in `☆` symbol. does `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");` solve your problem? also please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330695/java-scanner-not-going-through-entire-file

Comment: @John That seemed to fix it thank you so much that seemed to fix it.