# Removal of duplicate lines from a text file using java

Tags: java, duplicates, text-files

Can I read a text-file line by line up to the delimiter `--` and write the lines to a new file ?

Then I want to read the next block of lines between the two delimiters `--` and compare them to the previous ones.

If **three or more** lines are repeated then not write them to the file.

And so on until the end.

```
 public void removeDuplicateErr(String data) throws IOException {
    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(data)));
    String[] blocks = contents.split("--");

    String fileName = "output.txt";
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);

    int count = 0;
    int count1 = 0;

    for (String block : blocks) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if(count > 0) {
            String contents1 = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
            String[] blocks1 = contents1.split("--");
            for(String block1 : blocks1) {
                BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(block1));
                String line1 = br1.readLine();
                while (line1 != null) {
                    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(block));
                    String line2 = br2.readLine();
                    while (line2 != null) {
                        if(line1.equals(line2)) {
                            count1++;
                            if(count1 >= 3) {
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        line2 = br2.readLine();
                    }
                    line1 = br1.readLine();
                }
                if (!flag) {
                    pw.print(block);
                    pw.print("--");
                    pw.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        if(count < 1) {
            pw.print(block);
            pw.print("--");
            pw.flush();
        }
        count++;
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

#### Input sample

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
test 5
--
test 6
test 2
test 3
test 4
test 12
--
test 8
test 9 
test 10 
test 11 
test 12
--
test 1
test 3
test 4 
test 21
test 22
--
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4 
test 5
--
test 50
test 51
test 52 
test 53
test 54 
test 55
--
test 53
test 54
test 55
test 56
test 57
```

#### Expected Result

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
test 5
--
test 8 
test 9 
test 10 
test 11 
test 12
--
test 50 
test 51 
test 52
test 53
test 54
test 55
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try (suppose you have experience in Java File I/O) ? Please provide your code-attempt as [example] or at least show your research efforts (by links), e.g. search for [`[java] text file duplicate lines`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+text+file+duplicate+lines).

Comment: Are the "--" separators necessary?

Comment: get the file with separators

Comment: I'm asking do you want to print `--` between sections in the result? because this is not going to be consistent.. your second section may only contain duplicates of previous, and in this case, you'll end up having "-- --" separators.

Comment: In the result is not necessary.

Comment: Why is the last block in _expected_? It contains 3 lines (`53`, `54`, `55`) of the last in  _input_ (even in same order). Should then both blocks be removed from output?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion for an implementation:

```
public class BlockFilter {

    public void removeDuplicateErr(String data) throws IOException {
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(data)));
        String fileName = "output.txt";
        Files.writeString(Paths.get(fileName), getFilteredContent(contents));
        // TODO this method is not yet tested (but getFilteredContent() below)
    }

    public String getFilteredContent(String fileContent) {
        return getValidBlocks(fileContent).stream()
                .map(Block::getAsString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n--"));
    }

    private Collection<Block> getValidBlocks(String fileContent) {
        // create a list of Blocks...
        List<Block> allBlocks = Stream.of(fileContent.split("--"))
                .map(Block::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // ...and collect all, that are valid
        return allBlocks.stream()
            .filter(block -> isBlockValid(allBlocks, block))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private boolean isBlockValid(List<Block> allBlocks, Block block) {
        for (Block otherBlock : allBlocks) {
            if (otherBlock == block) {
                // we've reached 'block' and did not hit the invalid criterion so far
                return true;
            } else if (block.countEqualLines(otherBlock) >= 3) {
                // the block is invalid
                return false;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument 'block' must be contained in 'allBlocks'!");
    }

    private static class Block {

        private List<String> lines;

        private Block(String block) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(block);
            lines = Stream.of(block.split("\n")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        private long countEqualLines(Block otherBlock) {
            return otherBlock.lines.stream()
                    .filter(line -> lines.contains(line))
                    .count();
        }

        private String getAsString() {
            return lines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

At least the following Unit Test passes: ;-)

```java
    class BlockFilterTest {
    
        @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
        void getValidBlocks() {
    
            // Java 15 Multi-line String
            String fileContent = """
                    test 1
                    test 2
                    test 3
                    test 4
                    test 5
                    --
                    test 6
                    test 2
                    test 3
                    test 4
                    test 12
                    --
                    test 8
                    test 9
                    test 10
                    test 11
                    test 12
                    --
                    test 1
                    test 3
                    test 4
                    test 21
                    test 22
                    --
                    test 1
                    test 2
                    test 3
                    test 4
                    test 5
                    --
                    test 50
                    test 51
                    test 52
                    test 53
                    test 54
                    test 55
                    --
                    test 53
                    test 54
                    test 55
                    test 56
                    test 57""";
    
            String expected = """
                    test 1
                    test 2
                    test 3
                    test 4
                    test 5
                    --
                    test 8
                    test 9
                    test 10
                    test 11
                    test 12
                    --
                    test 50
                    test 51
                    test 52
                    test 53
                    test 54
                    test 55""";
    
            assertEquals(expected, new BlockFilter().getFilteredContent(fileContent));
        }
    }
```

Note, since BlockFilter has no state, all methods could also be static.

Comment: The class `Block` is a great idea. It helps to focus while developing the comparison ️. I am not sure if your naming and concept reflects the problem (domain): `filter`, `valid`, `contained block`, `count equal lines`. But the unit-test ️ verifies the working & tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Great starting code (in your original version).

**(!) Disclaimer:**
It's not very supportive, to change the code in your question, after someone has already answered. Even worse when you use the given answer to improve your code.

Changes in your code/problem, force all answers to change their solution too.

---

#### Issues

The criterion for *"duplicate" block* is:

> 3 or more lines [of that block] are [appearing in other blocks]

(remark: I added some specification inside brackets "[]" )

#### A Recipe with Ingredients

- read the **single input file** as a whole into a single buffer  `String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file")));`
- extract the contents into **blocks** (separated by `--`) use `String[] blocks = contents.split("--")`
- loop block by block: `for (block in blocks) {  blocks_out.append( deduplicateFrom(block, blocks);  }`
- write the resulting blocks back to a file (remember to append the separator after each block)

Now the crucial part detailed:
`blocks_out.append( deduplicateFrom(block, blocks);`

- inside the loop compare the current block with each of the other blocks
- the comparison can test on your criterion (3 or more lines duplicated)
- if no duplicates found, then add the (deduplicated) block to the result

#### What your program could log

Following would be the actions printed on console:

```
Split input into 7 blocks. Comparing them for duplicates in others. 
    comparing block 0
        duplicate lines of block 0 in 1: 3
    rejecting 'duplicated' block 0
    comparing block 1
        duplicate lines of block 1 in 0: 3
    rejecting 'duplicated' block 1
    comparing block 2
        duplicate lines of block 2 in 0: 0
        duplicate lines of block 2 in 1: 1
        duplicate lines of block 2 in 3: 0
        duplicate lines of block 2 in 4: 0
        duplicate lines of block 2 in 5: 0
        duplicate lines of block 2 in 6: 0
    adding 'unique' block 2
    comparing block 3
        duplicate lines of block 3 in 0: 3
    rejecting 'duplicated' block 3
    comparing block 4
        duplicate lines of block 4 in 0: 5
    rejecting 'duplicated' block 4
    comparing block 5
        duplicate lines of block 5 in 0: 0
        duplicate lines of block 5 in 1: 0
        duplicate lines of block 5 in 2: 0
        duplicate lines of block 5 in 3: 0
        duplicate lines of block 5 in 4: 0
        duplicate lines of block 5 in 6: 3
    rejecting 'duplicated' block 5
    comparing block 6
        duplicate lines of block 6 in 0: 0
        duplicate lines of block 6 in 1: 0
        duplicate lines of block 6 in 2: 0
        duplicate lines of block 6 in 3: 0
        duplicate lines of block 6 in 4: 0
        duplicate lines of block 6 in 5: 3
    rejecting 'duplicated' block 6
Total 'unique' blocks in output: 1
```

The only *unique* block I can recognize has numbers: 8 to 12. Where only `12` appears as *repeated* from the block before (1 duplicate line).

#### Research all ingredients on SO or the web

- [How to read a file into string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656797/how-to-read-a-file-into-string-in-java)

for the first bullet/ingredient, and so on.

Comment: I can't get the result I want

Comment: @GeorgiAtanasov, then post in your question, what you got as result and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: resulting -> test 1
test 2
test 3
test 4
test 5
--
test 8
test 9 
test 10 
test 11 
test 12
--
test 50
test 51
test 52 
test 53
test 54 
test 55
--
test 53
test 54
test 55
test 56
test 57

--

Comment: @GeorgiAtanasov Not here, please put them in your question. So everyone reading the question, can see what you are struggling with.